# "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect" because insert statement inside procedure

Tags: sql-server, r, stored-procedures, insert, rodbc

All tables involved are select, update, delete, insert granted. I am trying to execute a procedure and getting that error.

I used `odbcDriverConnect` because I guess any connection parameter will solve my problem (I tried `trusted_connection` and `autocommit`).

```
cc = odbcDriverConnect(connection = paste0('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=XX;UID=user;PWD=pass;autocommit=True;trusted_connection=true'))
rst = sqlQuery(cc, 'exec dbo.usp_mm_xx')
print(rst)
[1] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'exec dbo.usp_mm_xx'"
```

If I retire the `insert` from the procedure it runs ok.
I get the same error when I try to run the `insert`.

```
query=paste0('insert INTO dbo.X select * FROM dbo.Y a ',
             'where not exists (select 1 from dbo.X b where a.c1=b.c1 and a.c2=b.c2)')
rst=sqlQuery(cc, query)
print(rst)
[1] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'insert INTO dbo.X SELECT *  FROM dbo.Y a where not exists (select 1 from dbo.X b where a.c1=b.c2 and a.c2=b.c2)'"
```

The SQL statement runs ok on database, with same user.

Comment: Is `Excute` also granted?

Comment: yes, execute on procedure granted. It runs when I retire the insert.

Comment: Has the procedure the instruction "Set nocount on" in its first line ? It should has.

Comment: tks, @DennesTorres, it worked!  Would you like to answer, so I could vote you? Any reason for the `insert into` not working? Perhaps the line counting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your procedure needs the instruction "Set nocount on" in its first line.

The insert instruction inside the procedures has a result, a row count, that is returned to the client. When the insert appears before a select instruction, we are, for sure, expecting the select result in the client, however the client receives multiple results and the insert row count comes first.

Usually, when this happens, we receive empty resultsets. It appears RODBC is having a bigger trouble with multiple resultsets.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing @DennesTorres answer, to run an `insert into` with `sqlQuery`, one needs to prepend `set nocount on;` to the `insert` statement:

```
query=paste0('set nocount on; insert INTO dbo.X select * FROM dbo.Y a ',
         'where not exists (select 1 from dbo.X b where a.c1=b.c1 and a.c2=b.c2)')
rst=sqlQuery(cc, query)
print(rst)
character(0)
```